# How to filter a grouped dataframe with a conditional statement using dplyr?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements

I want to filter a dataframe using dplyr using a conditional. The condition I want to test is whether a country-year combination has two versions.

```
df <- data.frame(country = c("country1", "country2", "country1", "country2", "country3"), year = rep(2011,5), version = c("versionA", "versionA", "versionB", "versionB", "versionB"))
```

Here is what I tried after looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624161/use-filter-in-dplyr-conditional-on-an-if-statement-in-r):

```
df %>%
     group_by(country, year) %>%
     {if unique(version)==1 . else filter(version == "versionA")}
```

What I am hoping to get is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
country     year     version

country1    2011     versionA
country2    2011     versionA
country3    2011     versionB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the number of unique values we can use `n_distinct` and filter the rows based on that.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(country, year) %>%
  filter(if(n_distinct(version) == 2) version == 'versionA' else TRUE)


#  country   year version 
#  <fct>    <dbl> <fct>   
#1 country1  2011 versionA
#2 country2  2011 versionA
#3 country3  2011 versionB
```

Comment: Could you say a word about what the else TRUE does at the end of the filter line?

Comment: @TeaTree `TRUE` means it selects all the rows in the groups if the number of unique values in `version` is not equal to 2. If it is equal to 2 it will select only the rows where `version == 'versionA'`.

Answer (score 1):

After grouping by 'country', 'year', `filter` if number of distinct elements is greater than 1 return the 'versionA', or else return the first element

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(country, year)  %>% 
  filter((n_distinct(version)  > 1 & version == 'versionA')|row_number() == 1)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   country, year [3]
#  country   year version 
#  <fct>    <dbl> <fct>   
#1 country1  2011 versionA
#2 country2  2011 versionA
#3 country3  2011 versionB
```

---

Or this can be added in a `if/else`

```
df %>%
    group_by(country, year) %>%
    filter(if(n_distinct(version) > 1) version == 'versionA'
       else row_number() ==1)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   country, year [3]
#  country   year version 
#  <fct>    <dbl> <fct>   
#1 country1  2011 versionA
#2 country2  2011 versionA
#3 country3  2011 versionB
```

---

Or another option is `arrange`

```
df %>% 
    arrange(country, year, version != 'versionA') %>% 
    group_by(country, year) %>% 
    slice(1)
```

---

Or with `summarize`

```
df %>%
    group_by(country, year) %>%
    summarise(version = if(n_distinct(version) > 1) 'versionA' else first(version))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[if(n_distinct(version) > 1) version == 'versionA' 
          else 1], .(country, year)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R one-liner thanks (@akrun):

```
df[!(duplicated(df[1:2])),]
```

Base R one-liner:

```
df[!(duplicated(df$country, df$year)),]
```

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(!(duplicated(country, year)))
```

A more generic base R solution:

```
# Create a counter of versions for each year and country: 

df$tmp <- with(lapply(df, function(x){if(is.factor(x)){as.character(x)}else{x}}),
               ave(version, paste0(country, year), FUN = seq.int))

# Subset the dataframe to hold only the first record for each year/country: 

df[which(df$tmp == 1), ]
```

A more generic tidyverse solution:

```
df %>%
  arrange(version) %>% 
  filter(!(duplicated(country, year)))
```

Comment: It is a good line_liner and can be made more compact with `df[!duplicated(df[1:2]),]`, but is this based on the question posted i.e. if the order of rows are changed, this would give a different result

Comment: @akrun True, im sure this won't generalise well. Thanks for the tip I'll add it to my solution  (+1).

Comment: I think you need to `order` first and then it should worrk

Comment: i.e. `df %>% 
    arrange(country, year, version != 'versionA') %>% distinct(country, year, .keep_all = TRUE)` or your `filter(` version