# R: IF statement in dplyr::filter requires ELSE otherwise fails?

Tags: r, if-statement, filter, dplyr

Per [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624161/use-filter-in-dplyr-conditional-on-an-if-statement-in-r), one can include `if` statements in pipes and within `dplyr` functions. However for `filter`, it seems like one needs to use an `else` rather than just an `if`, otherwise the `filter` will return nothing, calling the error:

> no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class
> "NULL"

Which is rather misleading IMHO since I'm not using `filter_` and am not personally feeding the pipe a NULL class object. Min reprex:

```
data(mtcars)
a <- 1
mtcars %>% filter(if (a == 1) cyl == 6) # if in filter works
a <- NA
mtcars %>% filter(if (is.na(a)) cyl == 6) # is.na in if in filter works if it evaluates to true
a <- 4
mtcars %>% filter(if (!is.na(a)) cyl == a) # !is.na works if it evaluates to true
a <- NA
mtcars %>% filter(if (!is.na(a)) cyl == a) # doesn't work if it evaluates to false
# Input `..1` must be of size 32 or 1, not size 0.
```

One can use else to generate an output from the filter, by selecting a filter constraint that will include all results.

```
mtcars %>% filter(if (!is.na(a)) cyl == a else carb > 0
```

There's probably a better catch-all filter constraint, and indeed probably a more elegant way of doing this in general, but I couldn't find anyone else having found this problem so if nothing else, hopefully my progress serves its [usual purpose](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0535/6917/products/mistakesdemotivator.jpeg?v=1554328460).

Any intel as to whether this is a bug, or other ways to approach this, most welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can return `TRUE` in `else` condition which will select all the rows in case the condition is `FALSE` and is not dependent on the value in the column we are testing.

```
library(dplyr)
a <- NA
mtcars %>% filter(if(!is.na(a)) cyl == a else TRUE)
```

and to answer your question, yes `if` would require `else` part because without it, it would just return `NULL` which will fail in `filter`. See this example :

```
num <- 2
a <- if(num > 1) 'yes'
a
#[1] "yes"
a <- if(num > 3) 'yes'
a
#NULL
```

Hence when you use

```
a <- NA
mtcars %>% filter(if(!is.na(a)) cyl == a)
```

What actually happens is

```
mtcars %>% filter(NULL)
```

which returns the same error message.

Comment: makes sense, thanks again Ronak. `else TRUE` is a neat solution :)

Comment: @Ronak Shah, why `mtcars %>% filter(ifelse(!is.na(a), cyl == a,TRUE))` would not work?