# Conditionally filter rowwise on a dataframe for a column variable with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, conditional-statements, pipe

Here's my dummy data:

```
dummy_data <- data.frame (name  = c("apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "orange", "kiwi", "kiwi", "kiwi"),
                values = c("value_1", "value_2", NA,"value_2","value_3","value_3", NA, "value_3"),
                data = c("1234","2345","3456","4567","5678","6789","7890","1245"))

    name  values data
1  apple value_1 1234
2  apple value_2 2345
3 orange    <NA> 3456
4 orange value_2 4567
5 orange value_3 5678
6   kiwi value_3 6789
7   kiwi    <NA> 7890
8   kiwi value_3 1245
```

Ok so I want to filter for rows that are for name = 'kiwi', values = 'value_3' and number = 6789. I want this to be conditional as its going into a loop for a large data set. Some of the values are NA.

So desired outcome is the row #6:

```
  name  values data
6 kiwi value_3 6789
```

fruit_name is my dynamically assigned variable that will be 'kiwi' in one of the loops, value is my dynamically assigned variable that will be 'value_3' for that loop, and number is the same for 6789.

What I have now:

```
fruit_name <- 'kiwi'
value <- 'value_3'
number <- "6789"
```

Desired behavior: **filter for fruit_name (name col) and number (data col), then IF the values column for that ROW isn't NA, then filter on the value = value_3 (for this loop, which I'm not showing the loop structure for). If it is NA, then just keep the value as is (NA) and don't filter on it.**

```
df <- df %>% filter(name == fruit_name & data == number) %>%
           mutate( value = ifelse(!is.na(value), number, TRUE))
```

However, this isn't actually filtering, its just returning the variable number. I'd like it to filter. I've also tried doing something for the 2nd line similar to:

```
 filter(number %in% values)
```

or

```
filter(if (!is.na(value)) values == number else TRUE)
```

This gives an error:

*the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used*

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624161/use-filter-in-dplyr-conditional-on-an-if-statement-in-r#:%7E:text=https%3A//stackoverflow.com/a/47624205/3348414)

and neither of those worked. Kinda stuck here, advice would be appreciated. Thank you

**Additional data for 2ndary question (irrelevant to original question):**

Loop structure:

This is a list/key of the data I want to find matches to in my data frame for the dummy data:

```
list <- (fruit = c("apple", "orange", "kiwi", "kiwi"), 
vals1 = ("value_2", "value_1", "value_3", "value_3"), 
vals2 = c("4567", "5678", "6789", "4567") )


for (i in seq_len(nrow(list))) {

f_name  <- list$fruit[i]
val1  <- list$vals1[i]
val2   <- list$vals2[i]

assign(paste("df_", i, sep=""), dummy_data %>%  filter(name == f_name & data == val2, if(is.na(values)) is.na(values) else values == val1) )

}
```

Desired output: df_1, df_2 etc for each unique combo in the 'list' table above, for use in different processing later on.

Comment: Why do you have a loop? You should refrain from loops when using tidyverse unless you are doing simulations etc.

Comment: Its just a loop to make a group of filtered dataframes for a simulation

Comment: probably consider spliting? Also, note that you could just do `df %>% filter(name == fruit_name, data == number, values == value)` and you should get the results you want

Comment: The only issue is that sometimes the value field is blank so it would be NA == NA. I guess that works too though..

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to do it outside of a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `if` condition:

Assume your df is as follows:

```
df <- df %>%add_row(name='kiwi', data='6789')
```

Then for:

```
fruit_name <- 'kiwi'
value <- 'value_3'
number <- 6789

df %>%
  filter(name == fruit_name, data == number, 
         if(is.na(value))is.na(values) else values == value)

  name  values data
1 kiwi value_3 6789
```

---

```
fruit_name <- 'kiwi'
value <- NA
number <- 6789

df %>%
   filter(name == fruit_name, data == number, 
          if(is.na(value))is.na(values) else values == value)
  name values data
1 kiwi   <NA> 6789
```

Notice that I maintained the same code

#### Edit

You could also simply do:

```
subset(df, do.call(paste, df) == paste(fruit_name, value, number))
```

#### Edit 2:

Given the data in a list format, you could use :

```
merge(dummy_data, list, by.x = names(dummy_data), by.y = names(list))
  name  values data
1 kiwi value_3 6789
```

Comment: Thank you!
If you have any additional thoughts on doing this outside of a loop let me know.

Comment: @SqueakyBeak I have to see how the loop looks like. Just know that tidyverse is built upon MapReduce idea thus you can almost do completely without them

Comment: Sure, and trying to use loops less is part of my goal. I'll append the code above in one sec so you can see.

Comment: Is that true for if I iterate over all the rows in list though?

Comment: @SqueakyBeak you do not need for loop in your dataset. Just use `merge`. Check the updated code

Comment: So the desired output is separate data frames, dummy_data filtered into a subset by each row of list. so df_1 is dummy_data filtered by row 1 of list. The merge just gives me a big df.

Comment: @SqueakyBeak yes the big df returned by merge is the correct result for each row. You can now split rowwise. ie each row is the df_i you needed. Note that you are not supposed to POLLUTE the global environment by many variables which could be easily be put in a container like a dataframe or list etc. The resultng big df is the container that holds all of your results.

Comment: @SqueakyBeak if the results dont match due to the NA's, you should consider using match. ie `subset(dummy_data, do.call(paste, dummy_data) %in%do.call(paste, list))` Then each row corresponds to the row in list

Answer (score 1):

This computer doesn't have R installed so I'm limited in my test ability, but you might try

```
df <- df %>%
 filter( 
    name == fruit_name,  # comma works like an &
    data == number,
    is.na(values) | values == value
  )
```

Following up with the comments:

```
df |>
  add_row(name = 'kiwi', data = '6789') |>
  dplyr::filter( 
    name == fruit_name,  # comma works like an &
    data == number,
    is.na(values) | values == value
  )
```

keeps both the row with NA and the row with the value.

Here's a solution that only keeps the one without the NA:

```
df |>
  add_row(name = 'kiwi', data = '6789') |>
  dplyr::filter( 
    name == fruit_name,  # comma works like an &
    data == number,
    {if(all(is.na(values))) TRUE else values == value}
  )
```

Comment: Oooh that worked! Also, love to see more women here! (as a woman myself)

Comment: This will only work if the data values are distinct. eg try add a row `df %>%add_row(name = 'kiwi', data = '6789')` and the code will fail as it will filter both the NA row and the non-NA row @SqueakyBeak

Comment: NAs are always tricky.  (and why I warned that my test ability is limited).  would grouping help, @Onyambu?  (e.g. `rowwise()` before and `ungroup()` after?

Comment: I'm curious as to this answer, but I do unique() the data before this step

Comment: Notice that you should keep the row depending on what you are given. eg if given `value = NA` you should keep the row with NA and vice verse