Executing Else Statement in R (Including output from if statement)
I know my language is a little confusing in the question, but I'm not sure the exact terminology for asking it. Below (MRE), I want to filter Toyota but then I would want Toyota to execute with the else statement. How would I do that? (It could be something entirely different from an if / else statement, I also want it to incorporate multiple if statements). I get that it could work to make code in the else statement into a function and include it in the "if" statement (as I include below, which produces the output I want), but there are some reasons why this would become complicated, and it seems preferable to have it execute the if statement and then funnel that into the else statement, vs adding a function after each if statement (as I have in my second example).
make <- c("Mazda","Ford", "Toyota", 'Honda')
make <- sample(make, 32, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, .25, .25))
mtcars = cbind(make, mtcars)
View(mtcars)
cars = function(df, name){
  dat_1 = df%>%
    select(make, mpg, cyl, hp)
  if(colnames(mtcars)[1] == name){
    dat_1 = dat_1%>%
      filter(make == 'Toyota')
    return(dat_1)
  } else{
    return(dat_1%>%filter(cyl = c('6','8')))
  }
}

cars(mtcars, 'make')

This would produce desired output with extra if statement (and would work for what I want); however, it seems like there is a better solution.
cars = function(df, name){
  
  filter_fun = function(df){
    df%>%
      filter(cyl %in% c('6','8'))
  }
  
  
  dat_1 = df%>%
    select(make, mpg, cyl, hp)
  if(colnames(mtcars)[1] == name){
    dat_1 = dat_1%>%
      filter(make == 'Toyota')%>%
      filter_fun()
    return(dat_1)
  }
    if(colnames(mtcars)[3] == name){
      dat_2 = dat_1%>%
        mutate(cyl= case_match(as.character(cyl), '6' ~ '8'))%>%
        filter_fun()
      return(dat_2)
  } else{
    return(dat_1%>%filter_fun())
  }
}

Thank you to everyone who answered this question: As an aside, model for mtcars now seems to be stored as the index. How can you make the index an actual column (this was surprisingly hard to find)? (As another aside, what I'm trying to do is recode a variable name within the if/else, but I'm noticing that I can't pipe into recode. This does not work mtcars%>%recode(make, Toyota = 'toyota') but this does recode(mtcars$make, Toyota = 'toyota')?

What's the desired output?

"model for mtcars now seems to be stored as the index". The "index"  is called the row.names.

Is it this question, essentially? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624161/use-filter-in-dplyr-conditional-on-an-if-statement-in-r

Your first recode() returns an error because the first argument needs to be a column name but the first argument is mtcars. You need something like mtcars %>% mutate(make = recode(make, Toyota = "toyota")). However, recode() has been superseded by case_match() so you can use mtcars %>% mutate(make = case_match(make, "Toyota" ~ "toyota", .default = make)).

Also see ?tibble::rownames_to_column.

Thanks, I updated the question to reflect desired output! Also, thank you for the clarifications on row.names() and recode!

Here I convert row names to a column and separate out the make from the model. Then I apply a conditional filter using if and else, since it's just a single test I want to perform, not one for each row of the data (where you'd use ifelse or dplyr::if_else).
cars2 <- function(df, name) {
  df %>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column("make_model") %>%
    tidyr::separate(make_model, c("make", "model"), sep = " ", extra = "merge") %>%
    { if(name == colnames(mtcars)[1]) filter(., make == "Toyota") 
      else filter(., cyl %in% c(6,8)) }
  
}


cars2(datasets::mtcars, "make")
    make   model  mpg cyl  disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1 65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
2 Toyota  Corona 21.5   4 120.1 97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1


cars2(datasets::mtcars, "something else")
# note all the cyl values are either 6 or 8
       make       model  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1     Mazda         RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2     Mazda     RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3    Hornet     4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
4    Hornet  Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
5   Valiant        <NA> 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
6    Duster         360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
7      Merc         280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
8      Merc        280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
9      Merc       450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
10     Merc       450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
11     Merc      450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
12 Cadillac   Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
13  Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
14 Chrysler    Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
15    Dodge  Challenger 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
16      AMC     Javelin 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
17   Camaro         Z28 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
18  Pontiac    Firebird 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
19     Ford   Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
20  Ferrari        Dino 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
21 Maserati        Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8


Thanks for this, Jon...so what I'd be looking for, given your example, is for it to return nothing in Toyota (since there is no Toyota with cylinder > 6). Obviously, this isn't my goal; it's more about how do you take the execution of the if statement and funnel it into the else statement (such that exceptions to the if will only go through the else statement, but the if statement will still run through the else).

The update would be trivial; just filter for Toyata and then make the if / else output do either filter(TRUE) or filter(cyl %in% c(6,8)). Away from computer and can update later.

The only thing is then I'd want to add another if else statement for if it's Honda, do something else; if it's Merc do something else. I was just trying to create an MRE, but continually learning about creating the best possible MRE and maybe should have included multiple if / else statements?

Hi Jon, I updated my question with a solution (but the one that I don't think is the best because it introduces the same function in multiple places) vs just having it execute the if statement (and then continuing the contents of that if statement into the else statement).

Something like this?
Just notice that you will always filter by make == 'Toyota'. Then if the column name is not 'make', also filter by cyl.
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

cars <- function(df, name){
  dat_1 <- df%>%
    select(make, mpg, cyl, hp) %>%
    filter(make == 'Toyota')
  
  if(colnames(df)[1] != name){
    dat_1 %>% filter(cyl %in% c(6, 8))
  } else dat_1
}

set.seed(2024)
make <- c("Mazda","Ford", "Toyota", 'Honda')
make <- sample(make, 32, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.25, 0.25, .25, .25))
mtcars2 <- cbind(make, mtcars)

cars(mtcars2, 'make')
#>                      make  mpg cyl  hp
#> Mazda RX4 Wag      Toyota 21.0   6 110
#> Hornet Sportabout  Toyota 18.7   8 175
#> Duster 360         Toyota 14.3   8 245
#> Merc 240D          Toyota 24.4   4  62
#> Cadillac Fleetwood Toyota 10.4   8 205
#> Toyota Corolla     Toyota 33.9   4  65
#> Fiat X1-9          Toyota 27.3   4  66
#> Maserati Bora      Toyota 15.0   8 335
#> Volvo 142E         Toyota 21.4   4 109

cars(mtcars2, 'mpg')
#>                      make  mpg cyl  hp
#> Mazda RX4 Wag      Toyota 21.0   6 110
#> Hornet Sportabout  Toyota 18.7   8 175
#> Duster 360         Toyota 14.3   8 245
#> Cadillac Fleetwood Toyota 10.4   8 205
#> Maserati Bora      Toyota 15.0   8 335

Created on 2024-10-03 with reprex v2.1.0

Edit
If you also want to create a column with the row names, there are functions to do so in contributed packages.
But you don't have to load an extra package to use just one function, the following simple function will create such a column as the 1st one.
rownames_to_col <- function(x, new = "rownames") {
  y <- data.frame(row.names(x), x, row.names = NULL)
  names(y)[1L] <- new
  y
}
rownames_to_col(mtcars, 'make') |> head()
#>                make  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1         Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3        Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> 6           Valiant 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

Created on 2024-10-04 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you; but I think in your example Toyota cars should only have more than six cylinders, right?

James, can you clarify more how this is not what you want? The TRUE case is limited to cyl 6/8, as desired, right?

@James Only filter if colnames(df)[1] != name, right? If the condition is false, return dat_1 as is, that's what the function does.

Yeah, I see what you're saying. So it does get the correct answer, but if I needed to add in another if statement, then it wouldn't work, right? If, I then needed to recode some values if colnames(df)[1] == cyl, and I wanted to use this function for both make and cyl but to execute different things for each. But then to continue with the rest of the function once that code has been executed. Does that make sense?

Hi Rui, I updated my question with a solution (but the one that I don't think is the best because it introduces the same function in multiple places) vs just having it execute the if statement (and then continuing the contents of that if statement into the else statement). Thank you also for the row.names to columns function! And thank you for your help!
